# "Missing method body, or declare abstract." Jblue

Tags: java

Here's my code: (I pulled an old instruction thing to make a "coin flipping" program and I'm trying to re-write it.

```
//Name: Adam
//Approximate time to complete: Lel
//References: scrub

public class CoinFlip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Get a random number
        //Decide the outcome of the coin flip
        //Get a second random number
        //Decide the outcome of a second coin flip
        //Print out which flip had a higher score
        //Print out the maximum of the two flips
    }

    public static double random();
}
```

I keep getting the error "Missing method body, or declare abstract."

Why?

---

I have a question. How do I format the "{"s and stuff? Also, is how I put the "public static double random()" code correct? Or should I put it under the public class? I'm kinda confused on how to organize it and I don't think that looks right.

Comment: Please take the Tour and read the Help Center. Being a beginner does not mean you can ask in any which way. It's also irrelevant to the question. It's considered noisy and distracts from the problem.

Comment: Why do you think the error is occurring?

Comment: You should read some [basic tutorials for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) before asking on SO.

Comment: For formatting, check out Java coding convetions.

Answer (score 1):

`public static double random();`

This is an incomplete method-declaration in the context of your code. You need to provide a body for `random()` and that's what the "Missing method body" part of the message is telling you.

There are only two contexts where you can declare a method without providing a body (implementation), and this is where the "declare abstract" part comes in:

- You have an abstract class, and you will define this method as abstract using the `abstract` modifier `public abstract double random();`. It is expected then that a sub-type will provide the necessary implentation.
- You have an interface, and you define this method as part of the interface as `double random();`. It is then expected that a concrete implementation of the interface will provide an implementation for this method.

> How do I format the "{"s and stuff?

Java coding styles and conventions are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), but it hasn't been updated in since '99. So I guess they are technically official. The placement of braces tends to be a matter of preference, but usually some sort of convention is enforced. The most-common patterns I've seen are:

- Opening braces on the same line as the declaration/conditional-expression/looping-construct, and closing braces on their own line:

  ```
  if(...) {
     ...
  }
  ```
- Opening and closing braces on their own lines:

  ```
  if(...)
  {
     ...
  }
  ```

There are also some other, less-common styles which you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style).

> Also, is how I put the "public static double random()" code correct? Or should I put it under the public class?

You either need to provide an implementation (body), or you need to create your own abstract class and define that as an abstract method within that class. Then you need a class that extends the abstract class, and *that* class will provide the implementation for `random`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is quite self-explanatory

```
Missing method body, or declare abstract.
```

Now look at your method

```
public static double random();
```

which does not have a body. A method without a body is an abstract method and need to be marked so using `abstract` keyword. Marking the method as abstract will need your class to be marked as abstract too, not sure if you really want to do so.

If you just want a method to be non-abstract but with empty body then add empty body as mentioned here:

```
public static double random() {}
```

EDIT: As your method returns a value so you cannot have an empty body so you may either have to change the return type to void or provide a body to return a value :

```
public static void random() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

All methods need to include a method definition i.e everything after and including the first curly brace unless the method is declared abstract in which case the keyword abstract needs to be used in the method declaration and the class in which the method is placed ought to be abstract.

with regards to its ogranisation :

```
    public class CoinFlip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //method calls to static methods here like so :
    double answer=random();
    }
    //static methods here
    public static double random();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double random();
```

The above is syntactically incorrect. If you want to declare a method either assign it a blank body

```
public static double random() {}
```

or have a keyword 'abstract' in the method signature.

```
public double random() {}
```

** Note: In this case you will need to declare the class as static as well and remove static keyword from the method signature.

```
public abstract class CoinFlip { 
             /* your code */
  }
```

A class with even a single abstract method must be declared static.

Comment: "A class with even a single abstract method must be declared static." - This is not right.

Comment: Also `public static double random() {}` and `public double random() {}` won't even compile because the declaration provides a return type and you aren't returning anything.